# Defining a length function using tail

Tags: list, haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell and I am trying to define my own length function as follows:

`lengthz :: [a] -> a
lengthz [] = 0
lengthz n = 1 + length (tail n)`

Why does this not compile? And or, is there something wrong with my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `tail` is best to be avoided, since it can crash your program when you pass it the empty list. You should use (exhaustive) pattern matching instead when possible, which does not have the same problem -- e.g. `lengthz (x:xs) = 1 + lengthz xs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have a typo in your recursive call to `lengthZ`. Fixing this, we encounter a new type error:

> No instance for (Num a)

What this tells us is that in order to use the function `(+)`, we must include the typeclass `Num` as a constraint in our type declaration. We also include a different type variable for the elements of the list so that the function can be applied to lists containing elements of any type. We thus rewrite the function as follows:

```
lengthz :: Num b => [a] -> b
lengthz [] = 0
lengthz n = 1 + lengthz (tail n)
```

Which works just as we'd expect:

```
ghci>> lengthz [1,2,3]
3
ghci>> lengthz []
0
```

Comment: Why not `lengthz :: Num a => [x] -> a` you don't use the content of the list at all.

Comment: A constraint of `Integral b` would probably be better; what would it mean for a list to have a "length" of 1.5? Let the caller convert the length to a real type (for, say, computing an average) if necessary. (For example, `genericLengthz = fromIntegral . lengthz`.)

Comment: @chepner Since our definition wouldn't even lead us to get non-integral types anyways, isn't this a pretty poor justification? I understand that the prelude `length` function is constrained this way, but thought that people viewed this as an inconvenience.

Comment: `Prelude.length` is even further constrained; it only returns `Int`. `Data.List.genericLength` generalizes to `Num b => b`. Since there is no *practical* purpose to defining `lengthz`, I figured it was worth differentiating it from the existing functions in some way, namely by providing a type constraint that accurately reflects the possible return values.

Answer (score 3):

The type for your `lengthz` function is `[a] -> a`.

This means you're taking a list of `a` things and returning a single `a` thing. What if you had a list of `Bool`? You don't want the function to output a `Bool`. You want an `Int` to be returned, regardless of the type of the thing in the list.

The simplest fix would be to change the type of `lengthz` to `[a] -> Int`. This says that the argument can be a list of anything (`a` is the anything, `[]` says it's a list) and the return type is an `Int`.